# Remove dots from cluster plot (factoextra)

Tags: r, plot, cluster-analysis

Is there a way to remove the dots from the `fviz_cluster` function of the factoextra package (plotting package of factominer).

[image]

As you can see, this is a bit messy with the dots, I would like to keep the cluster centers and ellipsoids only.

`fviz_cluster(HCPC9CL, repel = FALSE, geom = "point", show.clust.cent = TRUE, ellipse.type = "norm", palette = trololo, ggtheme = theme_minimal(),
main = "Factor map")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest solution is to set `alpha = 0`.

Here is an example:

```
set.seed(123)
data(iris)
iris.scaled <- scale(iris[, -5])
km.res <- kmeans(iris.scaled, 3, nstart = 10)


fviz_cluster(km.res, iris[, -5],
             repel = FALSE,
             geom = "point",
             show.clust.cent = TRUE,
             ellipse.type = "norm",
             ggtheme = theme_minimal(),
             main = "Factor map",
             alpha = 0)
```

[image]

However I suggest not to remove the points, but rather to make them transparent, and use only color to distinguish them:

```
fviz_cluster(km.res, iris[, -5],
             repel = FALSE,
             geom = "point",
             show.clust.cent = TRUE,
             ellipse.type = "norm",
             ggtheme = theme_minimal(),
             main = "Factor map",
             alpha = 0.2,
             shape = 19)
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't thought at all about transparency! Thank you Sir!

Comment: In my plot I want to get rid of labels but they're still there even if I set `labelsize = 0`.